# Склонение фамилии на -ец

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Как правильно склонять мужскую фамилию Гедроец? срочно нужно для официальной бумаги

Comment: спасибо, Alex_ander, Вы очень помогли

Comment: @zlobinnv, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: спасибо, Niemand, тоже. Носителя всё же попытаться надо спросить, как ему лучше с "й" или с "е"))

Answer (score 1):

Гедроец, Гедроеца, Гедроецу, Гедроеца, Гедроецем, о Гедроеце

Видимо, затруднение связано с вопросом, нет ли в каком-то из падежей буквы "й" (как при склонении слова "заец" и пр.). Нет, поскольку исходить нужно из возможности восстановления фамилии из варианта со склонением. Например, существуют похожие по форме разные фамилии Подгаец и Подгайц - в случае замены "е" на "й" при склонении уже нельзя восстановить написание фамилии в именительном падеже.

Answer (score 0):

Подгаец – Подгайца. Так склоняется точно, поскольку Подгаец – известная фамилия, международный гроссмейстер, долгое время был тренером Анатолия Карпова.

Так что ответ не столь однозначен. Думаю, что зависит ещё и от желания носителя фамилии. Например, тренер сборной России по хоккею Олег Знарок настаивает, чтобы было Знарка, Знарку и т.д.

Comment: Я тоже знаю этого гроссмейстера, но в других кругах не менее известен музыкант Подгайц. Не исключено, что этот вариант фамилии когда-то возник именно из формы склонения в каких-то документах. Разумеется, в устной форме, в пределах круга общения почти с гарантией будет склонение через "й", но документы - другой случай.

А как ещё можно склонять Знарка? Он совершенно прав, если противостояит попыткам избежать склонения вообще. Несклоняемые мужские фамилии имеют характерные признаки (французские с окончанием на "а" и очень немногие другие виды).

Comment: У Знарка те же проблемы – с беглой гласной. Можно ведь склонять: Знарока, Знароку и т.д.

Comment: Я как-то не подумал - действительно, напоминает слово "пророк", причём существительного "знарок" я не знаю. Интересно, а были случаи, когда дама по имени Любовь требовала при склонении "Любви"?
В именительном падеже требования носителей фамилии - дело обычное. Просят ударение сместить, изменить "ё" на "е" или наоборот - с этим в отношении знаменитостей считаются какое-то время, но со временем забывают ("Чебышёв", "Алехин").
P.S. Любопытно, что гуглом уже находятся тексты с "Олег Знарк" :)

Answer (score 0):

Есть популярный человек из мира спорта - Анатолий Бышовец. Во всех СМИ его фамилия всегда склоняется - "Бышовца", "Бышовцу" и т.д. Если при склонении оставлять на месте беглую гласную, то такая фамилия (и ей подобные - Коринец, Могилевец, Голодец...) будет звучать крайне нелепо. В отличие от фамилии Знарок.